# can you use mutual information to determine how much one variable tells you about another

Tags: mutual-information

I wrote a Naive Bayes Classifier and want to be able to test how much information one variable gives about another.  The idea is to use the ones that are the most orthogonal and avoid using highly redundant variables.

My idea was to use the mutual information, but have found that it is not as clear cut as I first thought.  For example, if my variables are X = { 1, 2, 3, 4 } and Y = { 9, 10, 11, 12 }, then the mutual information would seem to be 2.  But if X = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 } and Y = { 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 }, then the mutual information is 3.  In both cases, however, if these numbers are lists (like columns in a database or spreadsheet), then X = 1 will always be paired with Y = 9 etc., meaning knowing one will always tell you the value of the other.  So if both cases have a 1 to 1 mapping between X and Y and the mutual information is different, how useful is the mutual information in determining how much you know about one variable by knowing the other?

Would some quantity like $$\frac{H(X,Y)}{H(X) + H(Y)}$$ or $$\frac{H(X,Y)}{I(X,Y)}$$ work better?  Does anyone have experience with determining how much one variable will tell you about another?

Here is a summary of the two examples.

Example 1

- X = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
- Y = { 9, 10, 11, 12 }
- H(X) = 2
- H(Y) = 2
- H(X,Y) = 2
- I(X,Y) = 2
- H(X,Y) / (H(X) + H(Y)) = 0.5
- H(X,Y) / I(X,Y) = 1.0

Example 2

- X = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }
- Y = { 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 }
- H(X) = 3
- H(Y) = 3
- H(X,Y) = 3
- I(X,Y) = 3
- H(X,Y) / (H(X) + H(Y)) = 0.5

  - H(X,Y) / I(X,Y) = 1.0

Comment: Article by Reshef might answer this question "Quite a lot, really." See Reshef, D., Reshef, Y., Finucane, H., Grossman, S., McVean, G., Turnbaugh, P., Lander, E., Mitzenmacher, M., and Sabeti, P. (2011). Detecting novel associations in large data sets. *Science*, 334(6062):1518–1524.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Relative entropy (or Kullback-Leibler divergence ) is the appropriate quantity to measure how much one variable tells about another one. Relative entropy is, unlike the mutual information, unsymmetrical. That means, it is possible that knowing a variable A tells everything about another variable B, even knowing B does not tell anything about A.

Comment: Kullback–Leibler divergence only tells you how different the distributions of two variables are. It has no relation to their joint distribution, only their separate (marginal) distributions, so it is unable to detect any structured relation between the variables which is the basis of one telling something about the other. The correct measure of information between variables is mutual information. It is related to KL divergence insofern as it is the divergence between the joint distribution of two variables and the product of the marginal distributions.

Comment: "it is possible that knowing a variable A tells everything about another variable B, even knowing B does not tell anything about A": I don't believe that is actually possible. Can you give an example?

Comment: If you know one's SIN (social insurance number), you will know the persons gender (at birth at least). If you know one's gender, you basically know nothing about the person's SIN.

Comment: Well, "basically nothing" is not the same as "not anything". Let's simplify matters and assume that the number of issued SINs is the same for both genders, say $n$. In that case the SIN tells you the value of the variable "gender", which has two equally likely values, so you get 1 bit of information. The other way round, knowing the gender reduces the number of possible SINs from $2n$ to $n$ – again an amount of information of 1 bit.

Comment: Of course the total amount of information in a SIN is $\log 2n$, which is much more, so relatively speaking you gain "basically no" information. In absolute terms though you gain exactly the same amount either way, 1 bit.

Comment: Excellent analysis. You are right, MI is the right the measure for mutual information, not the KL divergence.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use mutual information to determine how much one variable tells you about another – as a matter of fact, that's the exact purpose of mutual information.

The reason for the different results in the two examples is that in the second example you have more possible values for each variable, which means there is more information to possibly gain about it.

I assume you used the base-2 logarithm, such that information is measured in bits. In example 1 there are 4 possible values, each occurring equally likely, which means knowing the value of $X$ *or* of $Y$ constitutes an amount of information of $\log_2 4 = 2$ bits. Because there is a one-to-one-correspondence, knowing the value of $X$ means exactly knowing the value of $Y$ (and vice versa), which means the value of $X$ does not only constitute 2 bits about $X$, but also 2 bits about $Y$ (and vice versa).

In example 2 there are 8 possible values, which means knowing $X$ *or* $Y$ constitutes $\log_2 8 = 3$ bits, and again there is a one-to-one correspondence, so that knowing $X$ tells you 3 bits about $Y$ (and vice versa).

The formal MI result therefore makes perfect sense.